# Centering vertically in table cell with other rotated cells

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I would like to center the **Available Expression**, **Very Busy Expression**... **Live Variables** cells. The following code aligns the quoted cells only on the bottom of the cell itself: is there a way to center vertically even those cells? Thanks in advance.

```
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[italian]{varioref}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{examples}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\spheading}[2][10em]{% \spheading[<width>]{<stuff>}\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#1}{\raggedright #2}}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

  ......

  \begin{tabular}{c|M{20mm} M{30mm}}
      & forward ($flow$) & backward ($flow^R$)\\
    \midrule
    \spheading[4em]{must ($\cap$)} & Available Expression & Very Busy Expression\\
    \spheading[4em]{may ($\cap$)} & Reaching Definition & Live Variables\\
     \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: When you write `$flow$`, LaTeX typesets this as the quantities `f`, `l`, `o` and `w` all "multiplied together". You should use `$\mathit{flow}$` and `$\mathit{flow}^R$` instead. Also, one of your `\cap`s should be a `\cup`.

Comment: It's better if you post a complete compilable `.tex` file, starting with `\documentclass`. Otherwise people trying to reproduce your problem have to guess which packages (e.g. booktabs) you've loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a reasonable approximation by putting `\raisebox{-1.5em}{...}` around your `\rotatebox`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\spheading}[2][10em]{% \spheading[<width>]{<stuff>}
\raisebox{-1.5em}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{#1}{\raggedright #2}}}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{c|M{20mm} M{30mm}}
      & forward ($\mathit{flow}$) & backward ($\mathit{flow}^R$)\\
    \midrule
    \spheading[4em]{must ($\cap$)} & Available Expression & Very Busy Expression\\
    \spheading[4em]{may ($\cap$)} & Reaching Definition & Live Variables\\
     \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]