# How to make a table with multirow rotated cells?

Tags: tables, multirow, rotating, makecell

I am trying to make the table with automatically centered, rotated multirow cells. Something like in the picture, but with cells automatically fitted to their content:

[image]

I tried to apply [solutions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89115/how-to-rotate-text-in-multirow-table) given by @AboAmmar and @Seong, but these not ensure vertical centering within the specified number of rows. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523892/cell-size-with-multirow-and-rotated-content) is unclear, because `\multirow` command under `makecell` package accepts non-integer value of number of rows (?). [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115585/centering-vertically-in-table-cell-with-other-rotated-cells) is given some code, but the problem is that this engages fixed value (in `\raisebox` argument) which is proper only for one specific cell content. [The most similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551060/how-to-align-a-rotated-text-to-left-in-multirow-cell) is without answer.

In fact I need some function which should be named `\multirowrothead` - as a combination of `\multirowthead` and `\rothead` functions of the `makecell` package.
My code:

```
\documentclass[table]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{
        |l|
        S[table-format=2.1]|
        S[table-format=1.2]|
        S[table-format=2.1]|
        S[table-format=1.2]|
        S[table-format=2.1]|
        S[table-format=1.2]|
    }
        \hline
        % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246889/how-to-color-column-heads-determined-width-makecell
        \rowcolor{gray}
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\colorbox{gray}{\thead{First title in heading}}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\colorbox{gray}{\thead{Second title\\in heading}}} & &\\
        \hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-----|>{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}-%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|%
        }
        \rowcolor{gray}
        & & & & \colorbox{gray}{\thead{data\\description}} &
        {\multirowthead{-2}{Data\\description}} &\\
        \hhline{%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}-%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}-%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}-%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|>{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}-%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|-|-|%
            >{\arrayrulecolor{gray}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|%
        }
        \rowcolor{gray}
        \colorbox{gray}{\multirowthead{-2}{side-heading\\description}} &
        \colorbox{gray}{\multirowthead{-2}{data\\description}} &
        \colorbox{gray}{\multirowthead{-2}{data\\description}} &
        \colorbox{gray}{\multirowthead{-2}{data\\description}} &
        \colorbox{gray}{\thead{A}} & \colorbox{gray}{\thead{B}} &
        \colorbox{gray}{\multirowthead{-3}{Data description}}\\
        \hline
        Description 1 & 63.5 & 4.87 & 63.5 & 4.87 & 63.5 & 4.87\\
        \hline
        Description 2 & 88.4 & 5.13 & 88.4 & 5.13 & 88.4 & 5.13\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if you make the value of `a` smaller how will the word `Description`  fit in the first row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have the quantity `b` in green on your picture smaller because the (total) height of the rows 2 and 3 is constrained by the contents of the cells of the column 5.

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}[ hvlines , code-before = \rowcolor{gray!30}{1-3} ]   
    {
        c
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=1.2]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=1.2]
        S[table-format=2.1]
        S[table-format=1.2]
    }%
{\Block{1-3}{First title in heading}} & & & 
  \Block{1-2}{Second title\\in heading} & &
{\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{Data\\description}} &  
{\Block{3-1}<\rotate>{Data description}} \\
  {\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{side-heading\\description}}
& {\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{data\\description}}
& {\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{data\\description}}
& {\Block{2-1}<\rotate>{data\\description}}
& \Block{}<\rotate>{data\\description\hspace*{0.5em}} \\
& & & & {A} & {B} \\
Description 1 & 63.5 & 4.87 & 63.5 & 4.87 & 63.5 & 4.87\\
Description 2 & 88.4 & 5.13 & 88.4 & 5.13 & 88.4 & 5.13\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

- In `{NiceTabular}`, you merge cells both vertically and horizontally with the built-in command `\Block`.
- With the key `hvlines`, you draw all the rules excepted in the blocks (which is what is expected here).
- The built-in command `\rotate` is used to rotate contents of cells and blocks.
- You can color cells, rows and columns with commands in the key `code-before` (however, it's also possible to use a syntax similar to the syntax of `colortbl`). Usually, the output is good in all PDF viewers at all levels of zoom.
- **However, you need several compilations.**

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: About dimension b - you are right. I have a problem with compilation. Firstly environment NiceTabular was not recognized - similar problem as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558971/how-to-get-nicematrix-to-work-in-texlive-2019). But after execution `latex nicematrix.ins` on new `nicematrix.ins` nad `nicematrix.dtx` files I met new problem by compilation of the file with the exemplary table: `! LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type"
! 
! Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment
! __nicematrix-light-syntax'.`

Comment: For that problem, it will be easier to reply by email. Send me your log file: fpantigny@wanadoo.fr